# Consider $\Bbb R / \Bbb Q = \{ x+\Bbb Q : x \in \Bbb R \}$. Show that the quotient topology is the trivial one.

Tags: general-topology

> Consider the quotient group $\Bbb R / \Bbb Q = \{ x+\Bbb Q : x \in \Bbb R \} = \{\{x+q : q \in \Bbb Q \} : x \in \Bbb R\}$. Show that the quotient topology is the trivial one.

It seems that the elements of $\Bbb R / \Bbb Q $ are of the form $$\{x+ \Bbb Q : x \in \Bbb R \} = \{x, x + \frac12, x+\frac34 ,.. \}$$

To show that $\tau_{\Bbb R / \Bbb Q} = \{\emptyset, \Bbb R / \Bbb Q \}$, I think I need to show that for every open $O \subset \Bbb R / \Bbb Q$ there exists an $x_0 \in \Bbb R$ such that $\{x_0 + q : q \in \Bbb Q \} \notin O$? I’m confused about the setup here. What even is open set in $\Bbb R / \Bbb Q $? It’s a set of sets/equivalence classes whose preimages are open in $\Bbb R$?

The quotient map $\pi: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R / \Bbb Q $ is the one inducing the topology right?

Comment: Yes: an open set in $\Bbb R / \Bbb Q$ is a set (of classes) whose preimage is open in $\Bbb R$. Now use density of $\Bbb Q$ to show that there are only trivial open sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set $V\subset\mathbb R/\mathbb Q$ is open if
$$
\{x\in\mathbb R: [x]\in V\}
$$
is open in $\mathbb R$. Here, $[x]\in \mathbb R/\mathbb Q$ is the equivalence class of $x$, i.e.,
$$
[x]=\{y\in\mathbb R:y-x\in\mathbb Q\}.
$$
If $V\subset\mathbb R/\mathbb Q$ is open and non-empty, then
$\{x\in\mathbb R: [x]\in V\}$ should contain an interval, as is open in $\mathbb R$. Say $(a,b)\subset \{x\in\mathbb R: [x]\in V\}$, which means that
$$
x\in (a,b) \quad\Longrightarrow\quad [x]\in V.
$$

But, if $z$ is a real number, then there exists a $z'\in (a,b)$, such that $z-z'\in\mathbb Q$.

Hence, $[z]=[z']\in V$. Thus $V=\mathbb R/\mathbb Q$.

Comment: How is the equivalence class equal to $y$’s such that $y-x \in \Bbb Q$?

Comment: @Wondera The equivalence relation is defined as $x \sim y$ iff $y-x \in \Bbb Q$ so it's just the set of all $y$'s equivalent to $x$, as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Let $O$ be a non-empty subset of $\Bbb R{/}\Bbb Q$. This means that $U=q^{-1}[O]$ is non-empty and open in $\Bbb R$ (this is from continuity of $q$ and how the quotient topology is defined). Also, $U$ is saturated under $q$ (if $q(x) = q(x')$ and $x \in U$ then $x' \in U$ too); this follows from being an inverse image set of $q$. Now $U$ contains some interval $(a,b)$ with $a < b$.

If $x$ now is any real number, for some $q' \in \Bbb Q$ we have that $x + q' \in (a,b)$ (as $(a,b)-x$ is also an open interval and thus contains a rational) and so $q(x) = q(x+q')$ and $x+q' \in U$ so $x \in U$. It follows that $U=\Bbb R$ and $O=\Bbb R{/}\Bbb Q$. So the only non-empty open set in the quotient is the whole quotient.

Comment: Note that I use $q$, not $\pi$, for the map sending $x$ to its class.

Comment: Let’s see if I understood this correctly. If $O \subset \Bbb R / \Bbb Q$, then $q^{-1}[O] = U \subset \Bbb R$, where $U$ is open. Now since $U$ is open there exists $(a,b) \subset U$. Take now $x \in (a,b) \implies q(x) \in O$. Now it seems that we apply the archimedean property that in say between $(x,b)$ there is $q’$ s.t $x+q’ \in (x,b)$? How is then $q(x) = q(x+q’)$?

Comment: @Wondera no the argument to find $q’$ is different. See the answer. I just apply $\Bbb Q$ being dense which is not the Archimedean property. I use it for $a-x, b-x)$.

Comment: I see. Somehow in the answer you deduce that from $x+q’ \in U$, we have that $x \in U$, but doesn’t $x \in U$ follow directly from $x \in (a,b)$? Also how are $q(x)= q(x+q’)$ equal? Wouldn’t this mean that $[x] = [x + q’]$ are the same equivalence class?

Comment: @Wondera no $x$ was any real, $x+q’$ is in $U$. And than apply saturatedness. $x$ and $x+q’$ differ by a rational so they indeed define the same class. Which is what $q(x)=q(x+q’)$ says too.