# Topology of reals quotient by integers AND irrationals is indiscrete?

Tags: general-topology, equivalence-relations, quotient-spaces

This question is similar to [Consider $\Bbb R / \Bbb Q = \{ x+\Bbb Q : x \in \Bbb R \}$. Show that the quotient topology is the trivial one.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4228077) but not the same.

Consider the eq. relation on $\mathbb{R}$ as $x\simeq y \iff x=y$ OR $x,y$ are rational with $x=y+n$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Let $(X,\mathcal{T}_{\simeq})$ be the quotient space with quotient topology induced by the relation $\simeq$. Is it true that $\mathcal{T}_\simeq$ must also be trivial? Or is it some other topology?

I believe that it is: if $\pi:\mathbb{R}\to X$ is the quotient map and $U\neq\emptyset\subseteq X$ is an open set, then for $\pi^{-1}(U)$ must contain at least one element of all of the rational classes, but then to be open in $\mathbb{R}$ would also have to contain all of the irrational numbers since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is not true that an open set $U \supseteq \mathbb{Q}$ has to be equal to $\mathbb{R}$. On the contrary, we can even create such a $U$ with arbitrary small positive measure.

Comment: Well, every open superset of $\mathbb{Q}$ is compatible with the quotient map. Basically, the rationals don't constrain the irrationals that much. I don't really see a more convenient way to describe the topology you have here than its definition.

Comment: No, it isn't the indiscrete topology. For instance you can prove that it's a T1 topology (and obviously it has at least two points).

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio is it? What nbd separates $q$ from $q+1$ for $q$ is irrational?

Comment: @ChoripánConPebre $q$ and $q+1$ are the same point, so no neighbourhood can separate them.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio not when $q$ is irrational, in this case $q$ only relates to itself (so $[q]\neq [q+1]$). In fact, I think that no irrational $q$ (in $X$) can be separated from $q+n$ for any integer $n\neq 0$.

Comment: @ChoripánConPebre Ah, sorry, I misread your comment. Since $q$ is irrational, $\pi[\Bbb R\setminus\{q\}]$ is an open set that contains $q+1$ but not $q$. And vice versa.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio aren't you begging the question? Since $\pi(\mathbb{R}\setminus \{q\})=X\setminus \{[q]\}=\mathscr{C}\{[q]\}$, you claiming that $\pi(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{q\})$ is always open is equivalent to saying that $\{[q]\}$ is always closed, which is equivalent to $X$ being $T_1$. (I'm not trying to be annoying [sorry lol], I'm genuinely interested, so) how would one show that $\pi(\mathbb{R}\setminus \{q\})$ is open?

Comment: @ChoripánConPebre The definition says that a set $V$ is open (respectively, closed) in $X$ if and only if $\pi^{-1}[V]$ is open (respectively, closed) in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140397/discussion-between-choripan-con-pebre-and-sassatelli-giulio).

Comment: @ChoripánConPebre The discussion is over so let's not.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio damn, I'm trippin, you are right, sorry lol it is $T_1$

Answer (score 1):

The answer is negative, **$\mathscr{T}_\simeq$ is not trivial**. I'll just show an *example of a non-trivial open* set and explain how it came to mind (and some other facts about your space) later. Sin the real line carries the Euclidean topology, we'll refer to it as $E^1$. $X$ will be refered to as $E^1/\simeq$.

**The non-trivial open set.**
Let $a,b\in(0,1)$ with $a<b$. Let
$$G=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\big\{[x]\in E^1/\simeq\big|\; a+n<x<b+n\big\}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\pi\big((a+n,b+n)\big).$$
Notice that $[(a+b)/2]\in G$ and that $[0]\notin G$ so $G\notin\{\emptyset, E^1/\simeq\}$. We have that
$$\begin{align*}G&=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\Big(\pi\big((a+n,b+n)\cap\mathbb{Q}\big)\cup \pi\big((a+n,b+n)\cap\mathscr{C}\mathbb{Q}\big)\Big)\\
&=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\pi\big((a+n,b+n)\cap\mathbb{Q}\big)\cup \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\pi\big((a+n,b+n)\cap\mathscr{C}\mathbb{Q}\big)\\
&=\pi\big((a,b)\cap\mathbb{Q}\big)\cup \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\bigcup_{\substack{x\in(a+n,\,b+n)\\ x\in \mathscr{C}\mathbb{Q}}}\big\{\{x\}\big\}.\end{align*}$$
Where $\forall x\in\mathscr{C}\mathbb{Q},\; \pi(x)=\{x\}$ was used in the last line.
By taking pre-image,
$$\begin{align*}\pi^{-1}(G)&=\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(a+n,b+n)\cap\mathbb{Q}\right)\cup\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\bigcup_{\substack{x\in(a+n,\,b+n)\\ x\in \mathscr{C}\mathbb{Q}}}\{x\}\right)\\
&=\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(a+n,b+n)\cap\mathbb{Q}\right)\cup\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(a+n,b+n)\cap\mathscr{C}\mathbb{Q}\right)\\
&= \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(a+n,b+n).\end{align*}$$
Where $\forall x\in\mathscr{C}\mathbb{Q},\; \pi^{-1}\left(\big\{\{x\}\big\}\right)=\{x\}$ was used in the first line.
$$\therefore G\in\mathscr{T}_\simeq\setminus\{\emptyset, E^1/\simeq\}.$$

---

**The intuition**
Notice that the rational numbers are mapped to the circle (in the abstract sense that $x=x+n=x+2n=\dots$). The only problem with the topology is that $\mathscr{C}\mathbb{Q}$ isn't mapped to the circle; it remains a line. How could one imagine this geometrically?  The first thing that comes to mind is a circle (of ratiinal numbers) with a straight line (of irrationals) tangent to it. This intuition fails: consider any sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of rational numbers in $(0,1)$ that converge to an irrational number $q_0$ in $(0,1)$. Since $\pi$ is continuous, $\pi(a_n)\to \pi(q_0)=\{q_0\}$. Notice now that, if we let $m\in \mathbb{Z}$, then $a_n+m\to q_0+m$ and $\pi(a_n)=\pi(a_n+m)$, by continuity, again, $\pi(a_n+m)\to\pi(q_0+m)=\{q_0+m\}$. Then $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\colon=\big(\pi(a_n)\big)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is such that $b_n\to \{q_0\}$ and $b_n\to \{q_0+m\}$ (notice btw that since $\{q_0\}\neq \{q_0+m\}$, we've just proven that $E^1/\simeq$ is not Hausdorff) so $\{q_0\}$ and $\{q_0+m\}$ must be *close* for any irrational $q_0$ and any integer $m$. Our intuition must be re-shaped: Imagine the rational circle with the irrational tangent line again, grab each one of the ends of the tangent line and start forming a sort of spring on both sides of the circle (of same radius). One could imagine the space space $E^1/\simeq$ as this infinite spring with a circle in the middle and say that two elements are close if their angular position is close.

To define $G$, I just took every element of $E^1/\simeq$ that had an angle such that it's projection to the circle in the center was in $(a,b)$.

Comment: By some (most?) definitions of compact, the space must be first Hausdorff (by this definition, compact implies normal). In the section The intuition of my answer, I've proven that $E^1/\simeq$ is not Hausdorff, therefore it's not compact.

Do you still want to know if $E^1/\simeq$, not being compact, satisfies the property that every open covering has a finite subcovering?